# Trying to populate a drop down menu from a JSON file in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, drop-down-menu

Trying to make a drop down menu on React Native with the options coming from a JSON file. I have imported the JSON file and it is stored within the project, I have made a drop down menu using 'SelectDropdown' which appears correctly. I can display the values from my JSON file in a simple text field with the following code:

```
crimeJSON.map( record => {
        return (
            <Text>{record.Location} </Text>
        )
    })
```

However, when I try to put the above code as the 'data' for my dropdown menu it just displays [object Object] in every field. Can anyone help me with the correct code on how to make it work with my drop down?

I tried the above code

Comment: console.log the record - `record.Location` is an object, you need something from that object

Comment: @Abe so the JSON has records going like { ID : 1, Location:  Area1,    Stats 50%} and I want it to go through each record and give me its value for Location. How would I do that?

Comment: can you post exactly what you get from `console.log(JSON.stringify(record))` please

Comment: @Abe when i run that code i get a 'record' does not exist error. If it helps, my JSON was converted from a CSV file so its essentially 3 columns (ID, Location, Stat) and multiple rows. I don't think I am giving the records a name or anything in it